# My blog index page shows the last post as a title?

Tags: homepage, blog

From - Settings > Reading > I have selected a page I have designated as being the index page to show the latest blog posts...

I'm trying to problem solve and work out why the 'title tag' of the page pulls the title of the previous post?

The strange error stems from this header snippet of the blog index page - the  tag is pulling a blog post title - yet it is on another page?

```
        <div class="headline">
            <div class="container">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any ideas where and how I can trouble shoot this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to confirm, are you asking about the `<title>` tag or the `<h1>` tag? They are two different pieces. Both are most likely coming from either your theme or a plugin. Can you list your theme and plugins?

Comment: Where is this code in your loop?